# How to write JSON object into JSON array using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, file, object

I have a Python file that generates an object for a machine. Sample below.

```
 {
 "Date/Time": "2019-01-01 8:00:00",
 "Availability": 68,
 "Performance": 70,
 "Quality": 70
 }
```

I have another Python file with JSON data shown below. How can I insert the JSON object into the data array (Line 18, empty brackets) under 'machines' **without** copying and pasting the object over to this second file? Does it involve writing a Python file into another Python file?

```
[{
"countries": [{
    "countryID": "79",
    "countryName": "USA",
    "states": [{
        "stateID": "58",
        "stateName": "VA",
        "cities": [{
            "cityID": "13",
            "cityName": "RES",
            "locations": [{
                "locationID": "48",
                "locationName": "RTC",
                "locationZIP": 11111,
                "machines": [{
                    "machineID": "98",
                    "machineName": "RED",
                    "data": []
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

End goal:

```
[{
"countries": [{
"countryID": "79",
"countryName": "USA",
"states": [{
    "stateID": "58",
    "stateName": "VA",
    "cities": [{
        "cityID": "13",
        "cityName": "RES",
        "locations": [{
            "locationID": "48",
            "locationName": "RTC",
            "locationZIP": 11111,
            "machines": [{
                "machineID": "98",
                "machineName": "RED",
                "data": [{
                    "Date/Time": "2019-01-01 8:00:00",
                    "Availability": 68,
                    "Performance": 70,
                    "Quality": 70
                  }]
               }]
            }]
         }]
      }]
   }]
}]
```

Comment: Isn’t this just reading JSON, modifying it, writing it back to file?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to be able to work with Python data structures, then do the mapping into the target structure, and afterwards do a [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to write back to the target JSON file.

```py
import json

with open(file_name) as file:
    string = file.read()
    obj = json.loads(string)

target = map_to_target(obj)

with open(target_file_name, 'w') as out_file:
    out = json.dumps(target)
    out_file.write(out)
```

Comment: Is that code you posted supposed to be a third separate file? Or is it supposed to be inserted into the object generator file or JSON structure file?

Comment: I would separate it from the object generator file in order to not mix things up. It's python code and needs to be adapted to your use case of reading the date information and integrating it. For that purpose `map_to_target` needs to be implemented accordingly.

Comment: Still confused on what `map_to_target` means. What am I mapping?

Comment: Of course it all depends on how you want to organize it, but generally speaking the task is about converting one JSON structure A into a second JSON structure B. In order to have an easier time we first translate all JSON into Python objects. The we do a mapping from Python object A to Python object B - i.e. via a method `map_to_target`. When finished, we convert Python object B to JSON structure B and are finished.

Comment: Since I have 6 layers in my JSON structure (countries, states, cities, locations, machines, data) I have map 6 times?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple python script that decodes the bigger json file,  and inserts the smaller one (also decoding it).

Let’s say the data you want to add is in a file called “add_me.txt” and the big data file is “add_to_me.txt”. Both files contain json objects as you showed. You can do:

```
import json
with open(“add_me.txt”, “r”) as add_me, open(“add_to_me.txt”, “r+) as add_to_me:
    add_me_data = json.loads(add_me.read())
    add_to_me_data = json.loads(add_to_me.read())
    add_to_me.seek(0)

    add_to_me_data[<the right place>] = add_me_data
    add_to_me.write(json.dumps(add_to_me_data))
```

Comment: I can only add .txt files with this template? What about .py?

Comment: You can use whatever format you want to access the data as long as it is a json string...